# How to know is the main Scene in memory?

Tags: java, javafx, memory-leaks

I create application in JavaFX with a lot of controllers and Scene.

When I start MainApp.class it creates Stage primaryStage with Scene from startPage.fxml.
There are 2 buttons located which give a choice to open firstWindow or secondWindow.

I have 2 differs way to open that Windows
First one, When I open firstWindow I go back from startPage into MainApp and init firstWindow. It looks in MainApp.class as

```
public void initFirstWindow() {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxmlFirstWindow));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        firstWindow controller = loader.getController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

in FirstWindow.class

```
 @FXML
private BorderPane root;

public Controller controller;
...
```

The second way, I can start my secondWindow from the startPage when I press the button as

```
private MainApp main;
private BorderPane rootLayout;
private Stage childrenStage;
@FXML
public void btnSecondWindowOpen(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxmlSecondWindow));
        rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();
        SecondWindow controller = loader.getController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
        childrenStage = main.getStage();
        childrenStage.setScene(scene);
        childrenStage.show();

}
```

And the question is which way is better and is any memory-leaks while i start first or second Window?

As I wrote I have a lot of fxml which openes after first/second buttons, so I need to know.

Comment: Java is a garbage collected language, which means that when an object is out of scope and not reachable by the program its memory is freed up. So there are no 'memory leaks' possible, and you are safe as far as memory is concerned.

Comment: I don't see any purpose in holding a reference to the stage/root node in the last code snippet... This the first property is available via getter through `main` anyways, the second one doens't seem to be accessed. Therefore IF the controller is not available for garbage collection(which we cannot determine based on the code available), you'll keep a reference to the new scene's content and the stage...